# Hide Javascript inside SWF file

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

Instead of hidding my .JS using low criptography, I would prefer using a .SWF file to hide my .JS.

The problem is i have no knowledge in ActionScript 3, so i was thinking that maybe someone could give me a light in the end of the tunnel and tell me what APP i have to download to program the Swf file and what code i have to use for it to work.

If somebody haven't undestood i'll make it clear: I want to call Javascript using a SWF file.

Thank you, sorry for the bad english and good bye.

Comment: Your code isn't more safe in a SWF, you can decompile SWF to get code. You need tool for the operation, but a person with a tiny bit of motivation can find them easily.

Comment: I know that, but its still harder than Javascript alone in the page. I someone has the answer i would be grateful.

Comment: But here you should know that calling js files from HTML is exactly the same as calling it from Flash !!

Comment: Seems like over engineering to me. To be honest, your code is probably not that special. A minifier would probably do a better job of hiding your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, you can download FlashDevelop IDE, it will ask you to download Flex SDK ( the free compiler for as3 ).

You need to understand the class ExternalInterface ([Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)).

You need to run your code on webserver for security reason with the flash player.

In HTML, you need the param allowScriptAccess.

HTML
    
    
    
        
        CallJavascript

```
    <script src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var flashvars = {
        };
        var params = {
            menu: "false",
            scale: "noScale",
            allowFullscreen: "true",
            allowScriptAccess: "always",
            bgcolor: "",
            wmode: "direct" // can cause issues with FP settings & webcam
        };
        var attributes = {
            id:"CallJavascript"
        };
        swfobject.embedSWF(
            "CallJavascript.swf", 
            "altContent", "250", "250", "10.0.0", 
            "expressInstall.swf", 
            flashvars, params, attributes);

        $( document ).ready(function() {
            var flash = document.getElementById("CallJavascript");

            $( "#btnSend" ).click(function() {  
                flash.jsMySecretMethod( $( "#field" ).val() );
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        html, body { height:100%; overflow:hidden; }
        body { margin:0; background-color:#c0c0c0 }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="altContent">
        <h1>CallJavascript</h1>
        <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">Get Adobe Flash player</a></p>
    </div>
    <input id="field" type="text"/><button id="btnSend">Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

AS3

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author 
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _textfield:TextField;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

            _textfield = new TextField();
            _textfield.multiline = true;
            _textfield.wordWrap = true;
            _textfield.x = 20;
            _textfield.y = 20;
            _textfield.width = 200;
            _textfield.height = 200;
            _textfield.textColor = 0x000000;
            _textfield.text = "start";
            _textfield.border = true;
            addChild( _textfield );

            if ( ExternalInterface.available ) {
                ExternalInterface.addCallback( "jsMySecretMethod", mySecretMethod );
            }
        }

        private function mySecretMethod( str:String ):void {
            trace( str );
            _textfield.appendText( str );
        }

    }

}
```